# Regex operation to replace dynamic word/value from string

Tags: javascript, regex, cordova

I am working with phone directory app in phonegap
I need some javascript operation on mobile number 
for example if I have added country code for `Denmark 45`

Now I have to check if any mobile number contain `45` in starting of it like `4572342245`

Then I wants to remove country code and save it in another field like

```
CCode   Mobile
45      72342245
```

I have done it with

```
var numwithcode = "4572342245";
var newNumber = numwithcode .replace(/^45+/i, ''); 

alert(newNumber); //72342245
```

Same thing I want to do with, for e.g. `Australia 61` then

```
var numwithcode = "6172342245";
var newNumber = numwithcode.replace(/^61+/i, ''); 

alert(newNumber); //72342245
```

**What I want is to set this condition dynamic for any selected country code**

**for e.g.**

```
var countrycodehere = document.getElementById("countrycodefield").value;
var numwithcode = "6172342245";
var number = newNum.replace(/^countrycodehere+/i, ''); 

alert(number);
```

But, i failed with most of the testing I was doing for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a regex from a string can be done with

```
var re = new RegExp( string );
```

So you could do something like this:

```
var countrycodehere = document.getElementById("countrycodefield").value,
    numwithcode = "6172342245",
    re = new RegExp( countrycodehere ),
    number;

number = numwithcode.replace(re, ''),

alert(number);
```

Notice that the `+` won't get added, and it shouldn't. Because it meant that repetitions of the last digit in the area code would also be removed.

```js
function doAction() {

  var countrycodehere = document.getElementById("countrycodefield").value,
      numwithcode = document.getElementById("phonefield").value,
      re = new RegExp( countrycodehere ),
      number;

  number = numwithcode.replace(re, ''),

  alert(number);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Phone number: <input id="phonefield" type="text" value="6172342245"/><br/>
Area code: <input id="countrycodefield" type="text"/><br/>
<button onclick="doAction()">Process</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are genius man! Thanks a lot!!! I have also tried this `re = new RegExp( countrycodehere )` but I was confuse on how to set this new `re` into `replace(/^"+re+"+/i, '')` , and it wasn't give me an expected output, but you given me right way to use this `new RegExp`, thanks again. You saved my lots of time. Have a happy coding :) .